# Working with a number stored as a string

Tags: javascript, json, coffeescript, websocket

I guess this problem is common for CoffeScript and JavaScript. In my CoffeeScript script I receive a number like `606.0` over a websocket. Thus it comes as a string, being extracted from the JSON that arrived from the host. Now I want to work with this number, say, add something to it like:

```
# @x is the number presented as a string
@xx = @x + 100
console.log("res=" + @xx)
```

and what I get is:

```
res=606.0100
```

So it gets added as a string! And if I change the code a little, "saying" that 100 is float:

```
# @x is the number presented as a string
@xx = @x + 100.0
console.log("res=" + @xx)
```

The result is still the same.

My question is - how to explain to CoffeScript/JavaScript that this is a number, and not a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cast number from string just prepend a `+`:

```
n = '100'
alert n + 1 # 1001
alert +n + 1 # 101
```

http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/d77uq/